# Why this function doesn't works without the_post?

Tags: posts, loop

I'm a beginner wordpress developer, getting a lot confused in `the_post();` function, apparently it doesn't perform anything that can be visualized, but if I do not invoke this function my code breaks up. can someone please explain to me.
Even though I've sufficient knowledge of programming languages, but this thing is getting me confused.
Thanks in advance to helping hands

```
while (have_posts()) {

    the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php }
```

Comment: This query can be answered easily by looking at the WordPress documentation. In fact WP documentation has a specific topic on this particular function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to quote a brief, yet comprehensive, [comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/#comment-2477) on the official reference page for `the_post()`:

> Function `the_post()` checks whether the loop has started and then
>   sets the **current post** by moving, each time, to the next post in
>   the queue.

Additionally, the "current post" here refers to the current item in [`WP_Query::$posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) which is an array of posts returned by the WordPress query.

So for example, if `WP_Query::$posts` contains 5 items, the first call to `the_post()` will move the array pointer to the first item in that array, i.e. `WP_Query::$posts[0]`. Then the next calls move the pointer to `WP_Query::$posts[1]`, `WP_Query::$posts[2]` and so forth until the last item is reached.

So `the_post()` indeed doesn't display or even return anything, but without calling that function, you'd be stuck in an infinite `while` execution — for as long as the `have_posts()` returns `true` (i.e. there is a next item in `WP_Query::$posts`), hence as you've seen it, the page breaks.

And one more thing you should know, is that the current post is referenced by the global `$post` variable which is relied upon by `the_title()`, `the_content()`, `get_the_title()` and other `the_` and `get_the_` functions which display or retrieve/use data from the current post.

Comment: perfect explanation, all my doubts, if & buts are cleared.
Thank you so much

Comment: Why we use it in the else part? eg:- <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: Sorry @TharakaNuwan, I don't understand your question, or that your example did not have an `else`. If your question was why we use that **`if (have_posts())`**, though, then it's just to ensure we're displaying the posts (and possibly HTML/content outside the `while`) only when there are posts to display, which can be determined via [`have_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/).